# Using Migrations with Effort.EF6?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, effort

I'm using EF6 and I'm now setting up some tests for my aggregates. I've decided to use Effort.EF6 because I'd like to have those tests run without having to install an entire database engine.

My DbContext uses migrations and a seeding method that inserts some data. Can Effort.EF6 make use of that or should I use Effort's methods of seeding data ?

Answer (score 2):

The migrations take place automatically. I call the normal context seed method when I need populated data. Note that depending on the scope of your context (per test, or per test assembly) you may be running lots and lots of queries to do your seeding. That has both performance implications, and debugging issues, since any seeding bugs will start showing up as bugs in your tests, and any logging that happens during seeding will log as part of each test.

```
var connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
var context = new DbContext(connection);
context.Seed();
```

Comment: I'm a little confused with your answer. By default the `Seed` method exists as a `protected` method on the `Configuration` class, not on the context. Have you moved it to your context and you call it from `Configuration`?

Comment: @CraigW. Yes, we did, sorry, I forgot that that was not the usual setup when I made my answer.